# 404 Page redirect to custom pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

for e.g i have the following page gives 404 error

http://www.example.com/requirements/about-tn/about-us.html

I want the above page to the following url only if the above page is returning 404 error

http://rd.example.com/requirements/about-tn/about-us.html

How can i do that in .htaccess?

appreciated

regards,
Raja

Answer (score 1):

In the htaccess file in `www.example.com`'s document root, add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?requirements/about-tn/about-us.html http://rd.example.com/requirements/about-tn/about-us.html [L,R]
```